# Unauthorized Access Exception using Web Deploy to Site when the site root is a UNC path

Tags: deployment, msdeploy

I am trying to use Web Deploy to deploy a site where the Site is rooted on a UNC path instead of a local drive. This is because I want to have a shared configuration, and have all servers point to the same UNC for content. That would allow me to deploy to one server and have all servers updated at the same time. I've created a share with everyone  and users read/write. The NTFS permissions have the ID of the appDomain account as full control, and that is the same account that is configured as the specific user in Management Service Delegation. I can log on to the destination server as that ID, access the share and create/delete files.

However, I'm getting the following exception in my Microsoft Web Deploy log on the destination server:

> User:  Client IP: 192.168.62.174 Content-Type: application/msdeploy
>   Version: 9.0.0.0 MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0 MSDeploy.VersionMax:
>   9.0.1631.0 MSDeploy.Method: Sync MSDeploy.RequestId: c060c823-cdb4-4abe-8294-5ffbdc327d2e MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
>   MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US ServerVersion: 9.0.1631.0 Skip:
>   objectName="^configProtectedData$" Provider: auto, Path:  A tracing
>   deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client.
>   Request ID 'c060c823-cdb4-4abe-8294-5ffbdc327d2e'. Request Timestamp:
>   '8/23/2012 11:01:56 AM'. Error Details:
>   ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedUnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Unable to perform the operation ("Create Directory")     for the
>   specified directory
>   ("\someserver.mydomain.local\sharename\sitename\applicationName").    This
>   can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this
>   operation for the user credentials you are using.   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
>   ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The error code was 0x80070005.    ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path '\someserver.mydomain.local\sharename\sitename\applicationName' is
>   denied.    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.NativeMethods.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirectoryEx.CreateDirectory(String path)
>   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.CreateDirectory(String
>   fullPath, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject
>   source, Boolean whatIf)    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProviderBase.HandleKnownRetryableExceptions(DeploymentBaseContext
>   baseContext, Int32[] errorsToIgnore, Exception e, String path, String
>   operation)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathProviderBase.Add(DeploymentObject
>   source, Boolean whatIf)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source,
>   DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject
>   destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject
>   destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject
>   destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject
>   destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable
>   payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1
>   syncPassId)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData
>   asyncData)

This is shown as the following on the console of the machine where I run the deployment:

> C:\Users\PLaComb>"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy
>   V3\msdeploy.exe" 
>   -source:package='C:\Packages\Deployments\applicationName.zip'   -dest:auto,computerName='https://SERVERNAME:8172/msdeploy.axd',includeAcls='True'
>   -verb:sync  -disableLink:AppPoolExtension   -disableLink:ContentExtension   -disableLink:CertificateExtension   -setParamFile:"C:\Packages\Deployments\applicationName.SetParameters.xml"
>   -allowUntrusted Info: Using ID 'c060c823-cdb4-4abe-8294-5ffbdc327d2e' for connections to the remote server. Info: Adding sitemanifest
>   (sitemanifest). Info: Adding virtual path (JMS/admin) Info: Adding
>   directory (JMS/admin). Error Code:
>   ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER More Information: Unable to
>   perform the operation ("Create Directory") for the specified directory
>   ("\someserver.mydomain.local\sharename\sitename\applicationName").
>   This can occur if the server administrator has not authorized this
>   operation for the user credentials you are using.   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.
>   Error: The error code was 0x80070005. Error: Access to the path
>   '\someserver.mydomain.local\sharename\sitename\applicationName' is
>   denied. Error count: 1.

Comment: Does it have permissions to all the parent folders in the path?  that's what came to mind as something I've had more problems with than I care to count.

Comment: It does - The shared folders are on the root of what is E:\ on that server, and the account has full control of that folder and everything in it.

Comment: also having this error. i also work w/ OP